# Looking for some advice with Query

Tags: sql, azure

This is what I'm supposed to be doing. I'll copy it below.
Can't figure out how to put Initial and last name into one field.

Create a query to display the first initial of the Vendor contact first name and the full last name, and Vendor City, for Vendors whose contact last name begins with the letter “M” or those vendors that are located in New Jersey. Please put the initial and last name in one field. Put a period after the First name initial.

This is my code:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(VendorContactFName, 1)  As Intitals, VendorContactLName, VendorCity
    FROM Vendors
    WHERE VendorState = 'NJ' OR VendorContactLName = 'M'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT LEFT(VendorContactFName, 1) + '. ' + VendorContactLName as vname, VendorCity 
FROM Vendors 
WHERE VendorState = 'NJ' OR LEFT(VendorContactLName, 1) = 'M'
```